# How to determine current remote connection type? (rsh or ssh)

Tags: ssh, csh, rsh

I want to know if there is some methods to find out the current connection type to remote server (rsh or ssh?). Environment is Solaris 9, SuSE linux, csh.

Comment: Which is the server and which is the client?  Do you want to do it interactively, or have a script on the server figure it out?

Comment: Hi, Matthew. SuSE is the server login. Better to have a script or something like "echo $CONNECTION_TYPE". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `echo $SSH_CONNECTION;`.  SSH will set this environment variable on the remote server.  It contains the client IP, client port, server IP, and server port.  It should only be set for SSH connections.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : test `"$SSH_CLIENT$SSH2_CLIENT$SSH_TTY"` *AND* who is connected *AND* who is your parent.

The liquidprompt project has [a (bash/zsh) function](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt/blob/master/liquidprompt#L494) to do that, which looks like :

```sh
    # If this is an SSH connection.
    if [[ -n "$SSH_CLIENT$SSH2_CLIENT$SSH_TTY" ]] ; then
        # This is SSH.
    else
        # Get the host part of the who am i command.
        local sess_src="$(who am i | sed -n 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/p')"
        # Get the name of the parent process.
        local sess_parent="$(ps -o comm= -p $PPID 2> /dev/null)"
        if [[ -z "$sess_src" && "$sess_src" = *"shepherd" ]] ; then
            # This is a qrsh connection (cf. Grid Engine).
        elif [[ -z "$sess_src" || "$sess_src" = ":"* ]] ; then
            # This is a local connection.
        elif [[ "$sess_parent" = "su" || "$sess_parent" = "sudo" ]] ; then
            # This is a su/sudo
        else
            # This (may be) telnet.
        fi
    fi
```